# How to Fetch Dynamic input field array items value with different name php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form like below:

```
<form id="bookForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].title" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].isbn" placeholder="ISBN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0].price" placeholder="Price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get value of this form in php `$_Post` because the name of fields are like `<br/>name="book[0].title"**<br/>`?

and there are many dynamic different name input fields.

Comment: see `print_r($_POST)`.

Comment: As mentioned @panther, you can use either print_r() or var_dump() to visualize data and you'll see that "aggregate fields" will be managed as arrays

Comment: And you should be careful with dots in HTML tags name ! In the use of $POST[...] in PHP, you need to note this PHP rule: “Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example <input name="a.b" /> becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].” See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Are we not supposed to answer queries here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use same form then change name of all textbox like,

```
    <form id="bookForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0][title]" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0][isbn]." placeholder="ISBN" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0][price]" placeholder="Price" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default addButton"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And get value of this form like **echo $_POST['book'][0]['title'];**

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Sir How to loop this type of input array values

Answer (score 2):

If you can use for multiple books then use book[0].title like below,

```
<label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Book</label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book[0][title]" placeholder="Title" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change name attribute,

```
 <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book_title" placeholder="Title" />
</div>

book[0].title, this is not valid name.
```

You can now get something like this,

```
$_POST['book_title']
```